# Monotouch (mtouch) command line error MT0007 - "The root assembly does not exist"

Tags: ios, ipad, command-line, build, xamarin.ios

We are trying to use the MonoTouch mtouch command-line to run our app in the simulator.  We have a solution that has 3 projects in it, a library, a frontend app, and a test project.  When we use mtouch --installsim on the frontend app, everything works fine.  However, when we run mtouch --installsim or mtouch --debugsim on the test project, we get this error:

> error MT0007: The root assembly '--installsim=/Users/myuser/root4/trunk/App/UnifiedTests/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/UnifiedTests.app' does not exist

The above app builds and runs in the simulator fine from MonoDevelop, but from the command line, it doesn't work.  Here is the exact command line input:

> /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch --debugsim=/Users/myuser/root4/trunk/App/UnifiedTests/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/UnifiedTests.app --stdout=/Users/myuser/output --stderr=/Users/myuser/error
>
> /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch --installsim=/Users/myuser/root4/trunk/App/UnifiedTests/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/UnifiedTests.app --stdout=/Users/myuser/output --stderr=/Users/myuser/error

Any ideas on why this doesn't work?  There don't seem to be any significant differences between the tests app and the main app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because there is is no `--installsim` options in `mtouch` (and the unknown command is suspected to be an assembly name).

What's available are `--launchsim` and `--debugsim` and are both described [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Advanced_Topics/mtouch).

Try doing `mtouch --help` to see every options available or read the [man page](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=man%3amtouch%281%29) online.